# How do I get zipcodes based on latitude and longitude coordinates in R

Tags: r, ggmap

I have two columns, one containing latitude coordinates and the other containing longitude coordinates. I am attempting to create a third column that contains the zip codes based on the lat/long coordinates. I tried using library("ggmap") but I seem to be something wrong. I am not getting any zip code in the output. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
library("ggmap")
lat <- 38.8977 
lon <- 77.0365 
res <- revgeocode(c(lat, lon), output="all")
```

Comment: What have you tried? This seems to show one approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280145/convert-lat-lon-to-zipcode-neighborhood-name

Comment: You said it's not the correct output, but why not? What about it is wrong?

Comment: The value of res does not yield me a zip code. @camille

Comment: What _does_ it give you? Questions here should have a clear problem, rather than us trying to figure out what the issue is exactly. Right now for someone to know what the problem is, they'd need to run your code, which requires a Google API key, which AFAIK needs a credit card.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of errors.

1. The format is for calls to ggmap is: **first longitudes then latitudes**:

   ```
   revgeocode(c(lon, lat), output="all")
   ```
2. Also 77 degree longitude is east of the prime meridian, so that coordinate is probably in Russia.  If you are interested in the US then west longitudes are negative.

Thus the correct answer is:

```
lat <- 38.8977 
lon <- -77.0365 
res <- revgeocode(c(lon, lat), output="all")

res$results[[1]]$formatted_address
#[1] "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW, Washington, DC 20500, USA"
```